# HTTPClient.PostAsync. Exception: Connection was closed unexpectedly. C#

Tags: c#, post, async-await, task, httpclient

When I try to PostAsync, no response is coming back, even though the content is coming through.
The connection closes after 20 seconds or so, giving me an exception.

I'm getting a 200 OK, when Posting in Postman.

**This is the code calling the method with .Wait:**

```
StringContent sc = new StringContent(xml, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");
                
var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MyAsyncMethod(sc, ao.orderId).Wait());
t.Wait();
t.Dispose();
```

**This is the method:**

```
public async Task MyAsyncMethod(StringContent sc, string orderid)
{
    try
    {
        var response = await client.PostAsync("www.url.com", sc);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/Log/PostException.txt"))
        {
             writer.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }   
}
```

**The Exception:**

---

`An error occurred while sending the request. at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter1.GetResult() at ShipNoticeInvoiceAPI.BLL.ShipNoticeGenerator.<SendShipNotice>d__4.MoveNext()`

`System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly. at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)`

`System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal`

-2146233088

`mscorlib`

`Void ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)`

---

I hope that you have tried something simular and are able to help me out. I feel like I've tried everything.

Comment: Did you compare both calls in something like Fiddler ? Also the whole `Task.Factory.StartNew` / `Wait` thing you have going on is extremely suspect and most definitely wrong. Just `await` *async* methods...

Comment: you should try `MyAsyncMethod(sc, ao.orderId).RunSynchronously()` or get its result rather than running in a cpu thread

Comment: You probably used wrong uri/protocol. Also it could be deadlock, try to use `MyAsyncMethod(sc, ao.orderId).GetAwaiter().GetResult()` instead of `t` variable or just await the task

Comment: Thank you for your comments.None of the above worked out for me. I'm still getting the same exception.

Comment: @DanielRasmussen: Have you tried it with *no `Wait`s at all?* If so, please post a minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: I tried that already. 

`MyNormalMethod(sc, ao.orderId);

public void MyNormalMethod(StringContent sc, string orderid)
{
try
{
var response = client.PostAsync("www.url.com", sc); }`

The exception now says, that one or more errors happened.